# How do I implement command in Page.Resources?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My problem is when I'm adding command to button, which is located in ListBoxItem Style in Page.Reosources and click it, nothing happen. But if I add button in default grid, command will work.

XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="kkRedux.MVVM.View.SpecialView"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:kkRedux.MVVM.View"
      xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:kkRedux.MVVM.ViewModel"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="SpecialView">
    <Page.DataContext>
        <viewModel:SpecialViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="DieStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="11">
                            <Button Content="Click Mey"
                                    Width="100" Height="100"
                                    Background="Black"
                                    Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        
        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="panelTemplate">
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--ItemsSource ommited-->
        <ListBox Name="specialListBox"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DieStyle}"
                 ItemsPanel="{StaticResource panelTemplate}"
                 Background="Transparent"/>
        
        <!--this Command is working-->
        <Button Content="Click"
                Height="100" Width="100"
                Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

ViewModel:

```
internal class SpecialViewModel
    {
        public RelayCommand DownloadCommand { get; set; }

        public SpecialViewModel()
        {
            DownloadCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(o => Download(o));
        }

        private void Download(string arg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(arg);
        }
    }
```

P.S. Click's working fine, but I can't use it due to MVVM.

Comment: Add your error message/debugging information to your post.

Comment: It might work if you reference it with relative source. I dont remember but there might not be a datacontext in the style. (so relativesource findAncestor type window) then DataContext.CommandName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind to the `DataContext` of the parent `Page`:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.DownloadCommand,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page}}"
```

The default `DataContext` the element in the `ListBox` is the current item in the `Items` collection of the `ListBox`. That's why your binding doesn't work.